# How to use fetch with with sending the Id

Tags: rest, backbone.js

Hi I have the next model in backboneJS:

```
var Type = Backbone.Model.extend({
     url : "/api/SomeRoute"
});
var model = new Type({id:"MyAlias"});
model.fetch();
```

On the rest part In `SomeRoute` I have 2 actions which returns my Model. First which recieves the `Id` and returns the Model by `Id` and second without parameters which return the collection. But when I call fetch() in JS, it doesn't send the Id in the request. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an id attribute specified in a model. Then the fetch request will be like /api/SomeROute/id

Instead of url give urlRoot. **If urlRoot is specified then the models id will be appended.**

```
var Type = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : "/api/SomeRoute"
});
```

Comment: But as you can see I have setted the id in the constructor of `Type`. Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: and it's still going to ".../api/SomeRout" but not to ".../api/SomeRoute/MyAlias". Any Ideas?

Comment: Thanks, that is exectly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your url to next:

```
var type = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function(){
   return "/api/SomeRoute/" + this.get("id");
  }
});
var model = new Type({id: "SomeId"});
model.fetch();
```

Comment: I think it not a hack)) because backbone compile my url function )) but in other side if my model haven't id))

Comment: But what if you need to use `model.save()`? The POST request will go to /api/SomeRoute/SomeId. But it is not right by the rest.